# snap "network-manager" is already installed, but nmtui is not working

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

snap "network-manager" is already installed, but nmtui is not working.
when I command nmtui it shows to apt install network-manager. after command apt install network-manager here output is snap "network-manager" is already installed.

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove snap version by

```
snap remove network-manager
```

and then install deb-version instead

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```